# How can I autoselect the Terminal when I run Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have the C/C++ extension in Visual Studio Code. Whenever I build and run the program ( usually I do that by the keyboard shortcut CTRL+ALT+N, instead of clicking on the Run icon ) I find it annoying to press every single time on the Terminal zone, in order for me to give my program an input. Can I select a setting in order for my application to autoselect the terminal whenever I run the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really run and focus on the terminal with the same shortcut unless you install some extensions. But you can focus on the terminal by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>. You can also change the binding for that by going into:

```
file -> preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
```

And there you need to search for `workbench.action.terminal.focus` and then you can set your shortcut. Here is a link to another question if you still want to run your code and focus on the terminal with the same shortcut:
[Shortcut with multiple command in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160717/shortcut-with-multiple-command-in-vscode)
It gives an example on how to use extensions to execute multiple commands with the same key binding.